# Http Request with PHP CURL

Tags: php, http, curl, request

I need to perform an Http Request with the CURL method.

Here is the documentation of the service I have to connect with.

In order to invoke an API method, the client makes an HTTPS POST request on 
https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/method.

The request Content-Type header must be set to application/json and the post data (HTTP request body) must hold a JSON representation of input data.

Example of a valid HTTP request:

```
POST /api/ra/v1/ping HTTP/1.0
Host: app.kigo.net
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Content-Type: application/json
{
"PING" : "PONG"
}
```

The question is:

How to do it with CURL?

Comment: Could you show what you have put together so far, please?

Comment: What problems are you having in implementing a solution?  Can you talk to these?

Answer (score 0):

You need the SSL options for the https connection

followlocation will follow any redirects

return_transfer will save the response in a variable

```
$url = 'https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/ping';
$headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "PING=PONG");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $result );
```